# Errors accessing hash in mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I am having issues accessing my hash in mojolicious.

```
my %managers = (
'IT' => {
    'name' => 'Mike',
    'id'   => 1,
    'num_of_employees' => 15,
},
'Sales' => {
    'name' => 'John',
    'id' => 33,
    'num_of_employees'=> 50,
},
);
```

In perl I can access the data like `$managers{'IT'}{'name'}` would print out `Mike`. How would I do the same in mojolicious?

```
Being passed to my template
$g->stash(manage => \%managers);
<%== $manage{'IT'}{'name'} %>
```

The above throws an error.  printing `<%== $manage %> gives a HASH(0x1335430)` location.

Comment: " $g->stash(manage => \%managers);
<%== $manager{'IT'}{'name'} %> "
shouldn't you call both the same? either "manage" or "manager"?
your key in perl is "manage", but in your template you try to access "manager"

Comment: sorry was a typo.  but still getting an error when i print `<%== $manage{'IT'}{'name'} %>` error is ` Global symbol "%manage" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %manage"?)` and `<%== $manage %> gives a HASH(0x1335430)` is giving a location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your template `$manage` is a hash ref not a hash, so you need to dereference it by using the `->` operator like this

```
<%== $manager->{'IT'}{'name'} %>
```

Comment: I assumed that was an issue after more reading.  I am now getting `Can't use string ("Sales") as a HASH ref while "strict refs"`.

Comment: That error means that `$manager->{'IT'}` is set to the string `Sales` and not to another hash reference like you're expecting.

Comment: Not sure but now it's working.  Maybe a typo.  Thanks everyone.